# Flash object location

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

Hello i need to know there my flash application is running. 
in object src  my domain. but flash running on others domains.
and i want to know where. and send it with request on my server.
Thanks.
sorry for y bad grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at: [LoaderInfo.url](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/LoaderInfo.html#url)

```
class Main extends Sprite{

      public function Main(){
           trace(this.loaderInfo.url);  
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

write some code in your application to send it's domain to a server.
There are also good 3rd party tools that can track your app, i like mochi:
http://www.mochimedia.com/developers/